# How to expand an odd function into a series of cosines?

Tags: fourier-series

(Editing my [original post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521475/fourier-series-is-it-possible-to-expand-an-odd-function-into-a-cosine-series), also, already noticed [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247669/is-it-possible-for-cosine-functions-to-have-fourier-sine-series-expressions-or-s))

> Given for example the odd function $f(x)=x$ defined in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. I would like to expand this function into a cosine series. Is it possible to somehow expand $f$ into a function symmetric with respect to the axis $x=\pi$ (or $x=-\pi$) in order to do that?

Just to emphasize, this is not a homework question, just a general question I thought of when learning about expanding a function into a cosine series.

I know that if we are looking at a function defined on $[0,\pi]$ and want to expand it into a cosine series, we need to first define it as an even function in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, and then the coefficients of the sine terms will vanish.

Nevertheless, I am not quite sure how to expand a function defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$ that is not a priori even into a cosine series. As GEdgar suggested in the original thread, when I say "a cosine series", I don't mean $\sum a_n \cos(nx)$ necessarily (which obviously doesn't work), but also $f(x)=\sum a_n\cos(n(x-\pi))$ might work for me. Is there any book/paper/notes that discuss this case and also include a statement of the convergence theorems for such a case?

Comment: I supose you want to have the function periodic, so you develop the Fourrier series with sin, and then use $sin(A)=cos(A-\pi/2)$

Comment: In my opinion that's impossible 8f the functions in the expansions are periodic with period $2\pi. $ For example your modification $\cos n(x-\pi)=(-1)^n\cos nx$ does not help. It only  affects the coefficients.

Comment: Why not edit and reopen the old post with this one?

Comment: Marking as a duplicate of the original in the hope of avoiding further duplication of effort: [Fourier series - is it possible to expand an odd function into a cosine series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521475/fourier-series-is-it-possible-to-expand-an-odd-function-into-a-cosine-series)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't shift your cosine functions, it's really like you're trying to write a function as the sum of its projections onto other functions that are orthogonal to it.

Your projection gives you a sum of zero contributions, and it cannot represent the original function in a satisfactory way.

If you can shift them, shift cosines by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so that they become sines, antisymmetric w.r.t. the independent variables

$$\cos\left(\omega x -\frac{\pi}{2} \right) = \sin(\omega x)$$

and you have a set of antisymmetric base functions to project your antisymmetric function $f(x)$ onto.